# Permission when running script in Vagrant using Vagrantfile

Tags: permissions, scripts, rails, vagrant

I have created a vagrant box for running rails applications and I have managed to create it manually.

My next step was to create a shell script that I can include in the Vagrantfile so when creating new boxes all installation will be done automatically.

But when I reach the line:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I get this error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions': Permission denied
```

Works fine from CLI

Any ideas?

### **UPDATE**

I have fixed the mkdir error and the script runs from end to end with no apparent errors.

Now when I `vagrant ssh` and check my home directory I do not find any of the git repos I downloaded and installed using my script nor .bash_profile hence I can not `rbenv`

Any ideas why this may happen - what am I doing wrong?

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ls -a
.   .bash_history    .cache          .profile  .sudo_as_admin_successful  .veewee_version
..  .bash_logout   .bashrc        postinstall.sh  .ssh      .vbox_version
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

this is setup.sh:

```
# Update sources:
sudo apt-get -y update

# Install development tools:
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential

# Packages required for compilation of some stdlib modules
sudo apt-get -y install tklib 

# Extras for RubyGems and Rails:
sudo apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev

# Readline Dev on Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get -y install libreadline-gplv2-dev

# Install some nokogiri dependencies:
sudo apt-get -y install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

# Install Git
sudo apt-get -y install git-core 

# Install Sqlite
sudo apt-get -y install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev 

# Install Make
sudo apt-get -y install make

# Install NodeJS (Required for Rails)
sudo apt-get -y install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install curl nodejs

# Install RBENV
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
touch ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby 2.1.0
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

sudo sh ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh
rbenv install 2.1.0
rbenv rehash
rbenv global 2.1.0

# Install gems for Rails
# gem install rdoc
gem install bundler
# gem install rake 
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'
gem install rails
rbenv rehash
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st of all, you do not want a command that attempts to create a directory in your `~/.bash_profile`. Just i) create the directories once and leave it at that or ii) create them from the script instead or iii) at least use `mkdir -p` so it will fail silently if the dir exists. That said, the errors you are getting are permissions problems. What user is running `setup.sh`? It looks like you're not running it as `vagrant`.

Comment: this is how I call my script from within Vagrantfile `config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh"`

Comment: We need to know i) which user is launching the script (try adding `echo whoami` to `setup.sh` to check), and  ii) What the permissions are for `/home/vagrant/.rbenv/`.

Comment: I am not creating any folder myself - I think is the "offender" is `rbenv init -` in this case

Comment: I think we you do `vagrant up` the default root user `vagrant` kicks off the script. am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used vagrant but the errors you're getting come from the shell so somebody, somewhere is trying to run `mkdir /home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims` and the user doing do doesn't have the permissions. I'm guessing (from what you say) that for some reason you have that command in your `~/bash_profile` or `~vagrant/.bash_profile` but the user sourcing it doesn't have write access.

Answer (score 0):

This looks familiar to me. I've written some shell scripts for Vagrant provisioning and did hit a lot of issues before I can run it.

This could be related to `rbenv`, check the following

1. You don't need sudo to install Ruby via rbenv + ruby-build (see you get permission error?)
2. The correct way to install Ruby via rben is -> `rbenv install 2.1.2 -v`
3. After installing ruby via rbenv, you may have to restart shell (I used `exec $SHELL -l` which worked fine for my script)
4. For ubuntu, you are NOT supposed to use `$HOME/.bash_profile`, as per rbenv docs, you should be using `$HOME/.bashrc`

Fix all above and see if it works.